# Error in Autocomplete-search feature implemented using Angular Material

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

#### Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

#### HTML form

**Input Field**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="name" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

**Autocomplete HTML**

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <div *ngIf="filteredOptions" >
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let person of filteredOptions | async" [value]="person.name">
      {{person.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </div>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

#### Component with error

name and basis are decalared as FormControl:

```js
filteredOptions: Observable < string[] > ;

ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.name.valueChanges.pipe(map(val => this.filter(
    val)));
}
filter(val: string): string[] {
    var filteredData = [];
    if (this.persons) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.persons.length; i++) {
        if (this.basis.value === "name" || this.basis.value === "" || this.basis
          .value === undefined || this.basis.value === null) {
          if (this.persons[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name.value.toLowerCase()) !==
            -1) {
            filteredData[i] = this.persons[i];
          }
        } else if (this.basis.value === "id") {
          if (this.persons[i].id.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name.value.toLowerCase()) !==
            -1) {
            filteredData[i] = this.persons[i];
          }
        }
      }

      return filteredData;
    }*
```

Comment: This is the HTML:- <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="name" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                      <div *ngIf="filteredOptions" >
                      <mat-option  *ngFor="let person of filteredOptions | async" [value]="person.name">
                              {{person.name}}
                      </mat-option>
                   </div>
                    </mat-autocomplete>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the following line which fills your `filteredData` array with `undefined` values under certain conditions:

```js
filteredData[i] = this.persons[i];
```

In the beginning of the `filter` method, `filteredData` is an empty array. Then you check your `persons` array for a match and if one is found, you'll add it to the `filteredData` array at the same position as in the `persons` array: `filteredData[i] = this.persons[i];`.

Why is that problematic? Let's say the first two elements of the `persons` array weren't a match; the third one is a match. Hence, the third element of the `persons` array gets assigned to the third position of the empty `filteredData` array.

In Javascript, when you assign a value to a position that is higher than the size of the array, the array gets filled up with `undefined`.

Example:

```js
const array = [];
array[3] = 'test';
console.log(array[0]); // => undefined
```

#### Solution

Use `filteredData.push(this.persons[i]);` instead.

Comment: Great to hear. You can accept the answer as a solution then. :)